# SQL, How do I trim date to exclude the time?

Tags: sql-server, date, casting

for my query, I have to pull the dates from a table but they include the time as well. How do I trim in to not include the time?

```
CAST(m.START_DATE AS varchar(12)) AS StartDate
```

but what happens is, my result shows up as "Jun 12 2013". How would I change it to show up as 6/12/2013?

Comment: What database?  You have one part of your question about type conversion or datetime truncation, and another part about formatting.

Comment: sqlserver but i used convert(varchar(10), m.start_date, 101)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the cast-to-date function to strip out time parts:

```
SELECT CAST(m.START_DATE AS DATE)
```

You may found useful to read also about `CONVERT` function:

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187928.aspx)

Eg:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),m.START_DATE,102)
```

This would help you to format date in your favourite style.

Comment: i just used cast(m.start_date as date) and it worked. thank you! (i'm on sql server so the built in date() function didn't work.)

Comment: All database programmers should have this MSDN link bookmarked! imo :)

Comment: That is not English, try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: i used convert(varchar(10), m.start_date, 101), it worked even better!

Comment: Huh? What version of SQL Server has `DATE()` as a built-in function?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: sorry, you were right, i did get confused. Corrected now, thank u

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function
So it would be

```
SELECT DATE(m.START_DATE)
```

This works for MySQL

For SQL Server try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, m.START_DATE)
```

Comment: Not all rdbms's have that function.  So far, we don't know what that is.

Comment: The convert function, mentioned in the answer from LittleSweetSeas will enable Bob to be your uncle.

Comment: i used convert(varchar(10), m.start_date, 101), it is much better than my way haha

Answer (score 1):

You can lob off the time from a `DATETIME` field by using the `DATE` datatype in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CAST(m.START_DATE AS DATE) AS StartDate
```

For formatting, you can use `CONVERT()` and find a code that fits the format type you're after, but if you're using SQL Server 2012 you can use the handy `FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(m.START_DATE,'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

It is worth noting that `FORMAT()` is slow, I wouldn't use it for anything other than formatting output, which for the most part is best done outside of SQL (presentation layer).

Comment: +1 but just as an aside, [`FORMAT()` is seriously slow (about 2x over the next slowest method)](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time). There is also [an interesting bug that can shut down the SQL Server service in certain scenarios if you use the function with invariant culture](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/800817/).

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.. It will help you...

**IN SQL SERVER ->** `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),datestring,101)`

**IN MYSQL ->** `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%M/%d/%Y')`

**IN Oracle ->** `SELECT to_char(datestring,'MM/DD/YYYY')`

Comment: i just used cast(m.start_date as date) and it worked. thank you!

Comment: i used convert(varchar(10), m.start_date, 101), much better, thanks!